# how to make the same orientation for every navigation of tab bar controller

Tags: ios, swift, orientation, landscape-portrait

how to make the same effect of eletticitàTable in the other navigation controllers? i'd try to change the "if" in func application into appdelegate but nothing to do.
i would that only first page of navigation controller for all tabBar item can change from portrait to landscape mode. now only tabBar item elettricità table it's ok.
can we help me please?
sorry for my bad english

this is my appdelegate code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if let tabBarController = window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
        if let tabBarViewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers {
            if let projectsNavigationController = tabBarViewControllers[1] as? UINavigationController {
                if projectsNavigationController.visibleViewController is ElettricitàTable  //use here your own ViewController class name

                {
                    return .all
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return .portrait
}
```

Comment: You cannot make different children of a navigation controller have different orientations.

Comment: is there way for doesn't allow the landscape mode in a single view controller embed into navigation?